# parent().next().text() returning empty string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i have the following HTML that is generated dynamically with `$.get`

```
<div class="forum-post">
  <div>
    <span class="forum-title">Test post</span><span class="forum-type label label-forum-Discussion">Discussion</span>
  </div>

  <div class="forum-author">
    By: Jared De La Cruz on Thursday, June 27, 2013 7:17:43 PM
  </div>
  <pre>
    This is a test post
  </pre>

  <div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-mini btn-primary btn-forum-comment" id=""><i class="icon-comment icon-white"></i> comment</a>
  </div>

  <div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-mini btn-inverse btn-forum-comment-show" id=""><i class="icon-plus-sign icon-white"></i> show</a>
  </div>

  <div class="forum-comments">
    <div class="forum-author">
      By: Jared De La Cruz on Saturday, June 29, 2013 11:56:29 PM
    </div>
    <pre>
      This is a test comment
    </pre>
  </div>
  <hr style="border-top: 1px dotted #b0b0b0;border-bottom: 0px">
</div>
```

I have the following code:

```
// Button dynamic comment show
$("#forum").delegate(".btn-forum-comment-show", "click", function() {
  $(this).parent().next(".forum-comments").toggle();
  console.log($(this).parent().next(".btn-forum-comment-show").context.text);
  console.log($(this).parent().next(".btn-forum-comment-show").text());
  $(this).parent().next(".btn-forum-comment-show").context.text = 'hide';
});
```

The following code returns:

```
show
(an empty string)
```

I want to change the text based on the toggle action. Show/Hide as well as the icon any ideas? Thank in advanced!

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-mini btn-inverse btn-forum-comment-show" id="51ccf2471238f1cc13000003"><i class="icon-plus-sign icon-white"></i> show</a>
</div>
```

UPDATE:

`<i class="icon-plus-sign icon-white"></i> show` should change into on toggle `<i class="icon-minus-sign icon-white"></i> hide`

UPDATE 2: This seems to work. the issue was using .next() and not .find()

```
// Button dynamic comment show
$("#forum").delegate(".btn-forum-comment-show", "click", function() {
  $(this).parent().next(".forum-comments").toggle();
  var change = $(this).parent().find(".btn-forum-comment-show").text();
  var show = '<i class="icon-plus-sign icon-white"></i> show';
  var hide = '<i class="icon-minus-sign icon-white"></i> hide';
  if(change == ' show')
  {
    $(this).parent().find(".btn-forum-comment-show").html(hide);
  }
  if(change == ' hide')
  {
    $(this).parent().find(".btn-forum-comment-show").html(show);
  }
});
```

Comment: Why do you use `context`, do you know what that is?

Comment: nope! just inspecting the object. ignore that last line just for testing purpose

Comment: `text` is a **function** which is both getter and setter.

Comment: @elclanrs but its returning an empty string.

Comment: I don't see where are you using `text` as a function...

Comment: `delegate` is deprecated, btw.

Comment: sorry @elclanrs my fault, i had two windows open to copy past code with stackoverflow formatting

Comment: `id`s must be unique. This is actually important. You have two elements with `id="51ccf2471238f1cc13000003"`. You should not do that.

Comment: `next` only grabs the next sibling, if you pass a selector it will grab it if it matches,, but it won't grab any other sibling if is not _immediately_ next to it. So my guess is that your collection is empty.

Comment: There is only one `.btn-forum-comment-show` element in the entire thing. How can you select the "next" one, if there is only one to begin with

Comment: @JoeFrambach I understand, but im not really using that field. I will remove it, thx

Comment: what exactly would be the updated text? I mean what are you trying to update it with? Easiest way to think abou that would be to store that in a variable and pass it as an argument to text()

Comment: "<i class="icon-plus-sign icon-white"></i> show" should now be "<i class="icon-minus-sign icon-white"></i> hide"

Comment: @elclanrs what would i use to grab the info and change it?

Comment: @Jareddlc If you _did_ successfully set that anchor span's text, you would destroy the `<i>` element also contained in the anchor. Have you considered just having a `<span class="show"><i class="icon..."></i> show</span> <span class="hide"><i ...></i> hide</span>` and toggling their visibility instead of manipulating the elements' contents?

Comment: How would i then toggle their visibility?

Comment: I tried figure out whats going on so i created this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2UVqn/)

Comment: Not sure If you trying to do this, but if so, adding the icon change should be piece of cake http://jsfiddle.net/HPDKm/   edit:And just change the default text according to the default state of comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please change `next()` into `find()`:

```
$(this).parent().find(".btn-forum-comment-show").text("hide");
```

Comment: hahahah i just figured it out seconds before you posted it! thanks